# Two overlapped spheres with boundary lines

Tags: plotting, graphics

How can I have two overlapped spheres given by

```
Graphics3D[{Specularity[White, 50], Blue, Sphere[{0.0, 0, 0}, 1.0], 
Green, Sphere[{.7, 0, .7}]}, Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

in a such way that the result contains one sphere (for example the green one) as

[image]

and another (blue one) as

[image]

However, these spheres are drawn by another software, and their difference is related to distances between lines on the surfaces.

Comment: Use `ParametricPlot3D[]` instead if you really want mesh lines.

Comment: How can I penetrate them to each other with parametricplot3D?

Comment: How about this demonstration http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/VolumeAndSurfaceAreaOfTheIntersectionOfTwoSpheres/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following function based on `SphericalPlot3D` with `Mesh -> Full` and `Mesh -> All` options

```
ClearAll[sphere]

sphere[pos_, r_, mesh_, style_, points_: 20] := 
  GeometricTransformation[
   First@SphericalPlot3D[r, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> mesh, 
     MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> points, PlotStyle -> Directive[style]], 
   TranslationTransform[pos]];

Graphics3D[{sphere[{0.0, 0, 0}, 1, All, {Specularity[White, 50], Blue}], 
  sphere[{.7, 0, .7}, 1, Full, {Specularity[White, 50], Green}]}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might want to start with something like the following:

```
ParametricPlot3D[
  {Sin[u] Cos[v], Cos[u] Cos[v], Sin[v]}, {u, -Pi, Pi}, {v, -Pi, Pi},
  Mesh -> {45, 45}, PlotStyle -> White, Lighting -> "Neutral"
]

ParametricPlot3D[
  {0.8 + Sin[u] Cos[v], 0.8 + Cos[u] Cos[v], Sin[v]}, {u, -Pi, Pi}, {v, -Pi, Pi},
  Mesh -> {15, 19}, PlotStyle -> Directive[White, Opacity[0.5]], 
  Lighting -> {{"Ambient", RGBColor[0.9, 0.8, 0.9]}}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Besides so much thanks, I am trying to use of your answer to intersect two spheres.